# How to include highways type track or service in osm2po?

Tags: osm2po

What must I do for osm2po to take into consideration highways type track or service? I have processed one file and in the results with QGIS I can't see those types of highways.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick:

1. Open the osm2po.config in a text editor.
2. Uncomment (remove the '#' sign) for

`#wtr.tag.highway.service =        1, 51, 5`

and

`#wtr.tag.highway.track =          1, 71, 10`

3. Scroll down and check out the Allow/Deny-tags
   For example, "wtr.allow.highway.track = foot|bike", this means only foot and bike are allowed on this highway. This matches the "wtr.finalMask" above, so if your final mask is car, osm2po would not use the highway.track in routing.
   To fix this, change your final mask to foot|bike|car or change the wtr.allow.highway.track to foot|bike|car (you can use the final mask to control the transportation type).
   Notice the deny tags in this section too. You can play with those as you see fit. You can also add tags that are not mentioned, i.e. a wtr.allow.highway.service = foot|bike|car
4. Now you will need to rebuild your osm2po binaries/graph using the java -jar osm2po-xxx.jar prefix=hh hamburg.osm.pbf format.