# Is OSM2PO ignoring some ways?

Tags: osm2po

Recently I've started playing with OSM2PO and pgRouting but I've stumbled upon a weird problem which I'm not really sure where it comes from…

I've installed OSM2PO on Ubuntu, with no errors, and I've also imported latest Portuguese data from Geofabrik, also with no errors at all. When Osm2poService started running, I've tried a very simple routing from 40.64013,-8.61054 to 40.64021,-8.61112 and get a “no routing found”-like alert box. If you check http://goo.gl/maps/k6qyr and http://osrm.at/1KY you’ll see what the result should be.

I've also seen this problem while trying routings between other points, I found some routes that are really strange (not very optimized).

I think that for some reason there are some ways missing in my OSM data.

I'm using OSM2PO v4.5.25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is simple:
Some fool has tagged this street as "tertiary_link", which is nonsense.

PS: I've just corrected it in JOSM.

---

With reference to your question in the comment...

I don't know how Geofabrik interprets unknown tags.
Anyway, osrm is based on an algo developed in Karlsruhe, Germany.
Guess where Geofabrik have their main office ;-)
Keep in mind that even Geofabrik is a company at the end and not an osm health care.
Make up your own opinion about it. Cloudmade is dead and Geofabrik the only place where you can download osm extracts of this kind.

Back to your intrinsic problem:
Yes, if you know a tag, in this case our hot loved "tertiary_link", which osm2po ignores, then modify the osm2po.config file in order to include even this.

A very good howto can be found here:

[How to control what kind of tags / flags are imported with osm2po?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41286/how-to-control-what-kind-of-tags-flags-are-imported-with-osm2po)

and here

[How to include highways type track or service in osm2po?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41276/how-to-include-highways-type-track-or-service-in-osm2po)

Comment: OK... Thank you very much for your help! :-)

What I'm not getting (and this is the reason I was thinking this could be some OSM2PO problem) is why OSRM was routing this "properly" and OSM2PO not, with the same data source. Is it really the same data source?

Do you have any suggestion to avoid problems like this?

Thanks for your help and you work @ OSM2PO! :-)

Comment: I've got a very similar problem in china-OSM data. Is there a difference between highway=tertiary and higway=tertiary_link ? seems the later is not imported by osm2po

Comment: tertiary_link simply does not exist. It's a self invented tag. If some fool has tagged a street that way, just tell osm2po to include even this in your osm2po.config file.